# Neural network sine approximation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

After spending days failing to use neural network for Q learning, I decided to go back to the basics and do a simple function approximation to see if everything was working correctly and see how some parameters affected the learning process.
Here is the code that I came up with

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform', input_dim=1))
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
regressor.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
#regressor = ExtraTreesRegressor()

N = 5000
X = numpy.empty((N,))
Y = numpy.empty((N,))

for i in range(N):
    X[i] = random.uniform(-10, 10)
X = numpy.sort(X).reshape(-1, 1)

for i in range(N):
    Y[i] = numpy.sin(X[i])
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

X_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = X_scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y)

regressor.fit(X, Y, epochs=2, verbose=1, batch_size=32)
#regressor.fit(X, Y.reshape(5000,))

x = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:100*1j]
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
y = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:100*1j]
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
x = X_scaler.fit_transform(x)

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = regressor.predict(numpy.array([x[i]]))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_scaler.inverse_transform(x), Y_scaler.inverse_transform(y))
plt.plot(X_scaler.inverse_transform(X), Y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y))
```

The problem is that all my predictions are around 0 in value. As you can see I used an ExtraTreesRegressor from sklearn (commented lines) to check that the protocol is actually correct. So what is wrong with my neural network ? Why is it not working ?

(The actual problem that I'm trying to solve is to compute the Q function for the mountain car problem using neural network. How is it different from this function approximator ?)

Comment: Not sure what the learning rate here is, but does it get better if you train for more epochs?

Comment: I can't see any difference when I set it to 100

Comment: Using the sigmoid activation will lead to vanishing gradient problems, just don't use it.

Comment: I managed to get an approximation using a wider network and reducing the batch size while increasing the epochs, with the sigmoid. I just tried the same configuration but with relu and it doesn't work at all. What do you suggess for the activation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With these changes:

- Activations to `relu`
- Remove `kernel_initializer` (i.e. leave the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) `'glorot_uniform'`)
- Adam optimizer
- 100 epochs

i.e.

```
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='relu', input_dim=1)) 
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='relu')) 
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='relu')) 
regressor.add(Dense(units=1))
regressor.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

regressor.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, verbose=1, batch_size=32)
```

and the rest of your code unchanged, here is the result:

[image]

Tinker, again and again...

Comment: Could you develop the "tinker" thing in a few words ? It's not the first time I've seen it but I don't really understand (what it is and why it is)

Comment: @user3548298 It's just a (very) general expression, meaning "experiment, change, try & retry different things" etc, and don't feel bounded by the book. Supposedly all (great) inventors are "tinkerers"... ;)

Comment: So does it mean that there is no specific way to model a given problem and I have to brute force it ? Also I just tried your changes for a few runs and the results are very different from run to run. Are you sure you provided the right screenshot associated with it ?

Comment: 1) no, no brute force - the idea of tinkering is trial & experiment 2) screenshot is from my 1st (and only) attempt with the shown code

Comment: @user3548298 have a look at this tweet & linked post about tinkering https://twitter.com/hardmaru/status/980935074416803840

Answer (score 1):

A more concise version of your code that works:

```python
def data_gen():
    while True:
        x = (np.random.random([1024])-0.5) * 10 
        y = np.sin(x)
        yield (x,y)

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='tanh', input_dim=1))
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='tanh'))
regressor.add(Dense(units=20, activation='tanh'))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
regressor.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

regressor.fit_generator(data_gen(), epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=128)

x = (np.random.random([1024])-0.5)*10
x = np.sort(x)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, regressor.predict(x))
plt.show()
```

Changes made: replacing low layer activations with hyperbolic tangents, replacing the static dataset with a random generator, replacing sgd with adam. That said, there still are problems with other parts of your code that I haven't been able to locate yet (most likely your scaler and random process).

Comment: The only problem with my code is about the network (architecture and training). The rest is fine, it's just a small test script

Comment: I have been toying around with your code and making the architecture changes on the original still results in a linear y-pred. I can't figure out what's wrong specifically though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a good approximation by changing the architecture and the training as in the following code. It's a bit of an overkill but at least I know where the problem was coming from.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from keras import optimizers

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Dense(units=500, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform', input_dim=1))
regressor.add(Dense(units=500, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
regressor.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
regressor.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
#regressor = ExtraTreesRegressor()

N = 5000

X = numpy.empty((N,))
Y = numpy.empty((N,))

for i in range(N):
    X[i] = random.uniform(-10, 10)

X = numpy.sort(X).reshape(-1, 1)

for i in range(N):
    Y[i] = numpy.sin(X[i])

Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

X_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = X_scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y)

regressor.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, verbose=1, batch_size=2)
#regressor.fit(X, Y.reshape(5000,))

x = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:100*1j]
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
y = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:100*1j]
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
x = X_scaler.fit_transform(x)
for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = regressor.predict(numpy.array([x[i]]))


plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_scaler.inverse_transform(x), Y_scaler.inverse_transform(y))
plt.plot(X_scaler.inverse_transform(X), Y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y))
```

However I'm still baffled that I found papers saying that they were using only two hidden layers of five neurons to approximate the Q function of the mountain car problem and training their network for only a few minutes and get good results. I will try changing my batch size in my original problem to see what results I can get but I'm not very optimistic