# scikit-learn neural net beginner - results not what I expect

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

I have a simple example for which I am attempting to perform a classification using the MLPClassifier.

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# What are the features in our X data?
#  0. do .X files exist?
#  1. do .Y files exist?
#  2. does a Z.Z file exist?
# values are 0 for false and 1 for true

training_x = (
    [0,1,0],  # pure .Y files, no Z.Z
    [1,0,1],  # .X files and Z.Z
    [1,0,0],  # .X + w/o Z.Z
)
training_y = ('.Y, no .X, no Z.Z', '.X + Z.Z', '.X w/o Z.Z')
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                    hidden_layer_sizes=(len(training_x)+1, len(training_x)+1), random_state=1)
# training
clf.fit(training_x, training_y)
# predictions
for i in (0,1):
    for j in (0,1):
        for k in (0,1):
            results = list(clf.predict_proba([[i, j, k]])[0])
            # seems they are reversed:
            results.reverse()
            discrete_results = None
            for index in range(len(training_x)):
                if results[index] > 0.999:
                    if discrete_results is not None:
                        print('hold on a minute')
                    discrete_results = training_y[index]
            print(f'{i},{j},{k} ==> {results}, discrete={discrete_results}')
```

As I test it with all possible (discrete) inputs, I would expect for the predictions for the input cases: [0,1,0], [1,0,1] and [1,0,0] that I would see a close match to my three training_y cases and for other input cases the results would be under-defined and not of interest. However, those three input cases are not matched at all, unless I reverse the proba results where the [0,1,0] input does match and the other two are swapped. Here is the output with the reverse included:

```
0,0,0 ==> [1.1527971240749179e-19, 0.0029561479916546647, 0.9970438520083453], discrete=None
0,0,1 ==> [0.9999549772644907, 3.686866933257315e-08, 4.498586684013346e-05], discrete=.Y, no .X, no Z.Z
0,1,0 ==> [0.9999549772644907, 3.686866933257315e-08, 4.498586684013346e-05], discrete=.Y, no .X, no Z.Z
0,1,1 ==> [0.9999549772644907, 3.686866933257315e-08, 4.498586684013346e-05], discrete=.Y, no .X, no Z.Z
1,0,0 ==> [4.971668615064256e-68, 0.9999999980156198, 1.9843802638506693e-09], discrete=.X + Z.Z
1,0,1 ==> [1.3622448606166547e-05, 3.911037287197552e-05, 0.9999472671785217], discrete=.X w/o Z.Z
1,1,0 ==> [3.09415772026147e-33, 0.934313523906787, 0.06568647609321301], discrete=None
1,1,1 ==> [0.9999549772644907, 3.686866933257315e-08, 4.498586684013346e-05], discrete=.Y, no .X, no Z.Z
```

I have, no doubt, made a silly beginner's error! Help with finding it would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not expect to get anything meaningful with only 3 training samples; NNs do not work with such symbolic reasoning - they need *quantities* of data! The *spirit* of my answer here might be helpful: [Neural network for square (x^2) approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170460/neural-network-for-square-x2-approximation)

Comment: Thanks, @desertnaut . I appreciate the feedback. It makes sense to me. I increased my training by using the same data but replicating it 10,000 times. Unfortunately, it generates the same incorrect predictions in 2 of the 3 cases (or 3 of 3 if I don't reverse the results). I must still be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of probabilities from `predict_proba` are not "reversed", they are stored in (presumably) alphabetical order; you can check the order in the attribute `classes_`. And instead of discretizing yourself at the threshold 0.999, consider calling `predict`, which will take the class with largest probability, but more importantly translate back to the text of the class internally.

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. I now see the order of the classes is arbitrary. That doesn't make sense to implement it that way, but at least I know how to work with it now.

I was looking at the probabilities hoping to detect inputs for which the model was not trained. Since there is discrete matching, I did not want guesses, but certainty. However, with the 30k samples now, I get 8-9s of probability for predictions that were not trained. I can see my next step must be to train for all input cases, with undefined inputs returning an undefined output. 

Thanks for your help!